# How to run a transformers bert without pipeline?

Tags: aws-lambda, pipeline, huggingface-transformers

I have found myself dealing with an enviroment that does not support multiprocessing. How do I run my DistillBert without transformers pipeline?

Here is code right now:

```py
import json
import os
import sys

sys.path.append("/mnt/access")
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForQuestionAnswering
from transformers.pipelines import pipeline


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("After:",os.listdir("/mnt/access"))
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('/mnt/access/Dis_Save/')
    model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained('/mnt/access/Dis_Save/')
    nlp_qa = pipeline('question-answering', tokenizer=tokenizer,model=model)
    context = "tra"
    question = "tra"
    X = nlp_qa(context=context, question=question)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Error message I get right now:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "[Errno 38] Function not implemented",
  "errorType": "OSError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 18, in lambda_handler\n    X = nlp_qa(context=context, question=question)\n",
    "  File \"/mnt/access/transformers/pipelines.py\", line 1776, in __call__\n    features_list = [\n",
    "  File \"/mnt/access/transformers/pipelines.py\", line 1777, in <listcomp>\n    squad_convert_examples_to_features(\n",
    "  File \"/mnt/access/transformers/data/processors/squad.py\", line 354, in squad_convert_examples_to_features\n    with Pool(threads, initializer=squad_convert_example_to_features_init, initargs=(tokenizer,)) as p:\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py\", line 119, in Pool\n    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild,\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py\", line 191, in __init__\n    self._setup_queues()\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py\", line 343, in _setup_queues\n    self._inqueue = self._ctx.SimpleQueue()\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py\", line 113, in SimpleQueue\n    return SimpleQueue(ctx=self.get_context())\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py\", line 336, in __init__\n    self._rlock = ctx.Lock()\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py\", line 68, in Lock\n    return Lock(ctx=self.get_context())\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py\", line 162, in __init__\n    SemLock.__init__(self, SEMAPHORE, 1, 1, ctx=ctx)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py\", line 57, in __init__\n    sl = self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock(\n"
  ]
}
```

Other code:

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForQuestionAnswering
import torch
import json
import sys

sys.path.append("/mnt/access")

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("/mnt/access/Dis_Save/")
model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained("/mnt/access/Dis_Save/", return_dict=True)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    text = r"""
 Transformers (formerly known as pytorch-transformers and pytorch-pretrained-bert) provides general-purpose
architectures (BERT, GPT-2, RoBERTa, XLM, DistilBert, XLNet…) for Natural Language Understanding (NLU) and Natural
Language Generation (NLG) with over 32+ pretrained models in 100+ languages and deep interoperability between
TensorFlow 2.0 and PyTorch.
"""
    questions = ["How many pretrained models are available in  Transformers?",]
    for question in questions:
        inputs = tokenizer(question, text, add_special_tokens=True, return_tensors="pt")
        input_ids = inputs["input_ids"].tolist()[0]
        text_tokens = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(input_ids)
        answer_start_scores, answer_end_scores = model(**inputs).values()
        answer_start = torch.argmax(
            answer_start_scores
        )  # Get the most likely beginning of answer with the argmax of the score
        answer_end = torch.argmax(answer_end_scores) + 1  # Get the most likely end of answer with the argmax of the score
        answer = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_string(tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(input_ids[answer_start:answer_end]))
        print(f"Question: {question}")
        print(f"Answer: {answer}")
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(answer)
    }
```

**Edit:**
I run the code. It runs well on it's own, however I get an error whne running on API itself:

```
{
    "errorMessage": "'tuple' object has no attribute 'values'",
    "errorType": "AttributeError",
    "stackTrace": [
        "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 39, in lambda_handler\n    answer_start_scores, answer_end_scores = model(**inputs).values()\n"
    ]
}
```

Comment: The pipeline should work even in a single-core environment. Please include an error message in case you receive one. Please look at this [example](https://huggingface.co/transformers/task_summary.html) for extractive question answering.

Comment: What does multiprocessing have to do with a Transformers pipeline?

Comment: @cronoik "errorMessage": "[Errno 38] Function not implemented",
  "errorType": "OSError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 18, in lambda_handler\n    X = nlp_qa(context=context, question=question)\n",

Comment: @cronoik about multiprocessing being the reson for DistillBert not working... I have been told that by AWS support... that's all I know

Comment: @cronoik yes, there you go.

Comment: @cronoik it works! So the pipline is to blame...

Comment: Could you please submit an answer with the code that worked for you? At stackoverflow, we try to collect good questions and answers that are helpful for several people. Also please delete the comments that are not relevant anymore. Thanks!

Comment: @cronoik  Okay, so I have not updated it due to new Error I got, but it took some time to pin down as it is on a server and only shows up when run as API...

Comment: Well, that could be caused by a different `transformers` version or setting `return_dict` to False. You can fix that by removing `.values()` in case you receive a tuple with only 2 elements.